# Issue With Angular $scope.Watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a scope.watch like below, in my link function of the directive

```
scope.$watch(function () {
return scope.chartConfig;
}, function (value) {
console.log(value);
}, true);
```

Its trowing the below error

```
angular.js:12221 TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at isArrayLike (angular.js:278)
    at forEach (angular.js:332)
    at copy (angular.js:913)
    at copy (angular.js:879)
    at putValue (angular.js:944)
    at copy (angular.js:926)
    at copy (angular.js:879)
    at putValue (angular.js:944)
    at copy (angular.js:926)
    at copy (angular.js:879)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12221(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9055Scope.$digest @ angular.js:15574Scope.$apply @ angular.js:15824(anonymous function) @ angular.js:17580completeOutstandingRequest @ angular.js:5370(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5642
angular.js:12221 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at angular.js:68
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15594)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:15824)
    at angular.js:17580
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5370)
    at angular.js:5642(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12221(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9055Scope.$apply @ angular.js:15826(anonymous function) @ angular.js:17580completeOutstandingRequest @ angular.js:5370(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5642
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
```

Please find the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IXFYj5nHslfxKCZTlLoq?p=preview) link for the same

Comment: Angular detects this situation and prevents an infinite loop from causing the browser to become unresponsive.

For example, the situation can occur by setting up a watch on a path and subsequently updating the same path when the value changes. What is the need of scope.$watch there in that directive?

Comment: Yeap I understood why the issue occurs normally. But I want to know why its happening in the above mentioned example. I need the watch to redraw the graph if data changes.

Comment: as your code its look like, `scope.$watch('data', function (newVal, oldVal) { /*...*/ }, true);` here `true` idicates deep watch. So Is it require deep watch? or you need only watch data field under config object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is the error `TypeError: Illegal invocation`.

The object you are deep watching contains DOM elements, which `angular.copy` can't handle.

For example `chartConfig.data.datasets[0].controller.chart.chart.canvas` which is a reference to the actual canvas.

Furthermore, deep watching such a massive object is not good for performance.

Add a watcher on just the data you really need to watch.

Comment: Thanks watching scope.chartConfig.data.datasets[0].data solved the issue